# how to call java -classpath with C++ code in linux

Tags: java, linux

I've got a question when doing a project.

I need to call a Java program in a C++ program,
and it is in linux;
and the Java program has a package, so that I have to set the Classpath for it.

The problem is, I can't run the java program like this:

```
java -classpath Server/main/java/ Sever
```

But I can do this:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:Server/main/java

java Sever
```

However, the strange thing is that if I try to call the java program in other dir, even export CLASSPATH don't work. (I've changed the CLASSPATH so that it match the current dir)

I don't know why.
I have to do system call in C program, so export Classpath won't work,(I don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a relative path into your CLASSPATH that gets interpreted differently, depending on where you launch your program from. Use fully qualified paths instead.